# Magento 2.0.2 Product image upload error

Tags: error, permissions, magento-2.0.2, upload

I got an **error** like

> error":"Unable to create directory
>
> '/var/www/html/pub/media/tmp/catalog/product'.","errorcode" :0

While upload **product images**. I put **777 permission** `/var/www/html/pub/media` **folder**. but i got the **error**. kindly help me.

Comment: Pls create  manually  folder structure at location pub/media/tmp/catalog/product and try again

Answer (score 0):

Please check permission of media/catalog/products folder and try again.

Comment: Yes i checked. it also have 777  permission.

Comment: which php version you are using ?

Comment: i am using PHP 5.5.38. and magento 2.0.2 version

Answer (score 0):

Your issue in ***ownership***.

Your **web user** .. **(** CentOS: `apache and www-data` **)** does not have the ownership  to `create folder and files.`

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/legacy-file-system-perms.html  , how to apply ownership  in magento2.

As you have using ,please check out http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2412

the 2.1 release candidate, and with 2.0.6+, if you need permissions for generated assets of 664 and 775

### Little bad idea:

For a case, you can  change file permission from M`agento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException\DriverInterface` You need change `WRITEABLE_DIRECTORY_MODE = 0770;` to `WRITEABLE_DIRECTORY_MODE = 0775;`and `WRITEABLE_FILE_MODE = 0660 to WRITEABLE_FILE_MODE = 0664`.It is working for You.

Comment: I am following the instruction mentioned but not working